# Duplicate line and replace part of line multiple times

Tags: substitute, global-command

Considering this type of Json structure :

```
[
    {
        "id": "0000000000001",
        "en-US": "String 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "0000000000002",
        "en-US": "String 2"
    }
    ...
]
```

I want to get this structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0000000000001",
        "en-US": "String 1",
        "en-GB": "String 1",
        "fr-FR": "String 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "0000000000002",
        "en-US": "String 2",
        "en-GB": "String 2",
        "fr-FR": "String 2"
    }
    ...
]
```

Right now I am able to duplicate the lines with:

```
:g/en-US/t.

 [
        {
            "id": "0000000000001",
            "en-US": "String 1",
            "en-US": "String 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "0000000000002",
            "en-US": "String 2",
            "en-US": "String 2"
        }
        ...
    ]
```

I tried to concatenate that with sed to replace the string used as regex (en-US) for one of the goals without getting it worked.

How could I do the duplicate and replace together?

Comment: Using a macro would make this straightforward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to use one command by language you can do this:

```
g/en-US/t.|s/en-US/en-GB
g/en-GB/t.|s/fr-FR/en-GB
```

As you can see we reuse your command, and add another one to be executed with the `|` character.

**Edit** As suggested in the comments (Thank you @Doktor OSwaldo!) it is possible to put the command in a loop to avoid using it several time:

```
let lang=['en-GB','fr-FR'] | for i in lang | execute 'g/en-US/t.|s/en-US/'.i | endfor
```

---

Otherwise you can use a macro:

First put `en-US` in your search register with `/en-US<CR>`

Then record your macro:

```
qqnYpci"en-GB<Esc>Ypci"fr-FR<ESC>q
```

We can decompose it like this:

```
qq              Start recording in the register q
n               Go to the next occurence of the search (i.e "en-US")
Yp              Duplicate the line
ci"             Modify the content of the quotes
en-GB<Esc>      Put in the quotes 'en-GB' and exist insert mode
Yp              Duplicate the line
ci"             Modify the content of the quotes
fr-FR<Esc>      Put in the quotes 'fr-FR' and exist insert mode
q               stop recording the macro
```

You can then replay the macro as many times as you have lines that you want to duplicate.

---

Edit: If you want to call the macro only once (instead of specifying how many times it must be executed) you can use a recursive macro:

Firs you need to empty the register which will contain the macro (by recording an empty macro):

```
qqq
```

Then use the same macro but add `@q` at the end, this way the macro will call itself:

```
qqnYpci"en-GB<Esc>Ypci"fr-FR<ESC>@qq
```

One important detail is to use `set nowrapscan` this will make the macro fail when it execute the search after the last occurence in the file. Otherwise the macro will loop infinitely in the file and you'll get a lot of duplicate lines. See [`:h 'nowrapscan'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27nowrapscan%27).

Comment: Does the macro gets executed globally or do I have to execute it ocurrence by ocurrence?

Comment: It'll be repeated however many times you specify, e.g. `10@q` will repeat 10 times. Go to the top of the file, execute the search, play the macro as many times as blocks/ids you have.

Comment: @Dez:  Layer is right in this version you have to specify how many times it has to be executed. You can also use a recursive macro: first empty the `q` register with `qqq` then call the `q` register at the end of the macro: `qqnYpci"en-GB"<Esc>Ypci"fr-FR"@qq` before calling the macro make sure to set `set nowrapscan` (I'll edit my answer)

Comment: @Dez if you need to do this for a lot of languages, you can pack the first solution from statox in a for loop: `:let lang=['en-GB','fr-FR'] | for i in lang | execute 'g/en-US/t.|s/en-US/'.i |  endfor` just insert all languages you want into the `lang` list.

Comment: @statox one liners work wonderfully. Macro not so because my lack of knowledge about them. Sent some minor corrections to macro lines and explanations. Upvoted.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I feel more confident with your expanded solution of `statox` single liners.

Comment: Yup sorry for the typo in my macros I don't know how I messed that up, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @statox please feel free to add my line to your answer if you like. Since i have taken everything except a dumb for loop from your answer, I won't write a own answer.

Comment: I feel more confident with @DoktorOSwaldo expanded solution of your single liners. Update it and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without sed running over the text multiple times, you can use the sed "hold space" to save the line and then make replacements and print the modified line:

```
sed -e "\
    /en-US/{h;\
        x;h;s/en-US/en-US/;p;\
        x;h;s/en-US/en-GB/;p;\
        x;h;s/en-US/fr-FR/;p;\
    d;}"
```

(this example uses line continuationations to make it easier to see what is going)